# Could you help me understand this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across this sentence: "恋愛してもいい歳だ"google translator says it means: "I'm old enough to love" but is that really what it means?
Could you please explain this grammar pattern to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While I understand it is hard as beginner to even understand how all different grammar points are parsed in a sentence. But basically what you have here is the てもいい grammar -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53288/16104 . And a noun phrase grammar -> https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/advanced-adjectives-noun-phrases-particular-particles/ . You should try to avoid GT if possible, it makes wrong assumption more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that is about [age of consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent)?

Here is no deep meaning

恋愛 → love
してもいい → can do / allowed to do
歳 → age